# infix to postfix notation... error in test case loop

Tags: c++

this is code to convert infix to postfix for test cases i used while loop for the test cases but its not iterating for required number of inputs eg if i enter numofenput as 4 its iteating for 3 cases... Plz help me with this...

code here

```
    int main()
    {
     stack s;int token;char x;init(&s);int numofenput;

     scanf("%d",&numofenput);
     do
      {
        while((token=getchar())!='\n')
        {
         if(isalnum(token))
         printf("%c",token);
        else
            if(token=='(')
                push(&s,'(');
            else
              {
                 if(token==')')     
                 {
                   while((x=pop(&s))!='(')
                   printf("%c",x);
                  }
                  else
                   {
                     while((priority(token))<=(priority(top(&s))) &&!isempty(&s))
                    {
                      x=pop(&s);
                      printf("%c",x);
                     }
                      push(&s,token);
             }
         }
     } 
       while(!isempty(&s))
       {
          x=pop(&s);
         printf("%c",x);
       }
        numofenput--;
         }while(numofenput>0);
      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: What does the number of test cases have to do with "infix to postfix"?  `int num_tests = whatever;  for (int i = 0; i < num_tests; ++i) { your_code }`

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
}
    numofenput--;
} while( numofenput>0 );
```

to:

```
}
    numofenput--;
} while( numofenput>=0 );
```